# Split string into string arrays of X characters

Tags: java, android, string

I have a string `"thisisanexample"`. I want to split this into for example 4 char arrays like this:

```
group[0]="this"
group[1]="isan"
group[2]="exam"
group[3]="ple"
```

How can I do this?

Edit:

```
String str = "thisisanexample";
String[] arr = str.split("(?<=\\G.{4})");
c.drawText(arr[0], 100, 100, textPaint);
c.drawText(arr[1], 100, 200, textPaint);
c.drawText(arr[2], 100, 300, textPaint);
```

Comment: You can use the method substring and a loop

Comment: What had you try already?

Comment: Ah ok! I thought maybe there is already some code does this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You've to split on empty character after every 4 characters. The following code will do that:

```
String str = "thisisanexample";
String[] arr = str.split("(?<=\\G.{4})");
```

Basically, it splits on empty space, which is preceded by - which is governed by *look-behind* `(?<=...)`, any 4 characters. The `\\G` tells regex to start matching where the previous match ended.

If you feel a bit uncomfortable with regex, you can write a loop, that will iterate `str.length() / 4` times. On each iteration, take the 4 characters starting from current index, using `String#substring()` method.

Comment: @Downvoter Care to comment. What exactly is wrong in the answer?

Comment: It's a big leap from don't know how to loop and substring a String to use regex to split. By the way I am not the downvoter ;)

Comment: @Averroes Fair point. I've added an approach based on loop and substring, that OP should be able to follow.

Comment: Check the edit in the question. I have a code like this but only arr[0]=ex, rest of them is arr[1]="ample"

What  is wrong here?

Comment: @user3316779 That shouldn't be the case. Try it again. Make sure the regex is same as one posted in the answer. Replace `4` with `2`.

Comment: Unfortunately, it only splits the first 4 characters. Then gives an error:

java.lang.arrayindexoutofboundsexception length=2, index=2

Comment: @user3316779 Well, it's running fine on my machine. Try iterating over the array, and print each element. What do you get?